# How to use for loop tag inside chart.js template

Tags: django, chart.js

Hello guys i am having trouble using for loop in chart.js template i do not know how to use for loop tag inside chart.js template in order to get some data dynamically i am unable to find complete tutorial of chart.js and django kindly help me please.

**template**

```
var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
var defaultData = []
var labels = [];
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(i){
        labels = i.newlabels
        defaultData = i.newdata



var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: defaultData,
        backgroundColor: "#4e73df",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "#2e59d9",
        borderColor: "#4e73df"
       borderWidth: 1

    }]
},

});
},


    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
```

**views.py**

```
class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        qs_count = User.objects.all().count()

        av = Add.objects.aggregate(
                bud=Sum('budget'),
                exp=Sum('expense'),
                budexp=Sum('budget')-Sum('expense'))   # I WANT TO DISPLAY THIS DATA

        labels = ["Black", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
        default_items = [qs_count, 23, 2, 3, 12, 2]
        data = {
                "newlabels": labels,
                "newdata": default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: data: defaultData, here  or anywhere just want to display using for loop not directly

Comment: Like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56082109/chart-js-integration-to-django-project

Comment: I think this has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65813922/12201407